# TabPage from tabcontrol does not show data in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, tabcontrol

I am facing issue in tabcontrol of Windows application.

We have a tabcontrol on 1 windows form on which first tab is by default and other tabs we are adding dynamically at runtime.
In first case while we opening the form, we able to see all the controls in both the tabs i.e. (Default and other tabs)
Although, when we try opening the form for second time, data is being getting added into the form if we debug but while showing, it shows blank in other tabs which are getting added dynamically.

In CustomgroupControl class, i am adding controls dynamically like textbox, dropdown, grid and etc. Although this is working in first case, but not showing controls in second case. (Flow of code is same for both the cases)

Below is attached screenshot in link and shown sample source code

[Screenshot for above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWu5F.png)

```
public void renderTabpage(Dictionary<string, List<Field>> subHeaderMap, TabPage currentTabPage, AsynchTabRenderer asynchTabRenderer, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        currentTabPage.SuspendLayout();
        TableLayoutPanel headerTableLayout = createNewheaferTableLayoutPanel(currentTabPage.Name + TABLE_LAYOUT_NAME_SUFFIX);
        currentTabPage.Controls.Add(headerTableLayout);
        headerTableLayout.ColumnCount = 1;
        headerTableLayout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        headerTableLayout.RowCount = 0;
        headerTableLayout.SuspendLayout();
        foreach (string subHeaderName in subHeaderMap.Keys)
        {
            if (asynchTabRenderer != null && asynchTabRenderer.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                CustomGroupControl customGroupControl = createAndPopulateSubheaderGroupControl(subHeaderMap[subHeaderName], subHeaderName);
                headerTableLayout.RowCount = headerTableLayout.RowCount + 1;
                headerTableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                headerTableLayout.Controls.Add(customGroupControl, 0, ++headerTableLayout.RowCount);
            }
        }
        headerTableLayout.ResumeLayout(false);
        headerTableLayout.PerformLayout();
        currentTabPage.ResumeLayout(false);
        currentTabPage.PerformLayout();
    }

 private void detailsTabControl_TabIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            tabIndexChangedEvent(((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab);            
    }

    private void tabIndexChangedEvent(TabPage tabPage)
    {
        try
        {
            //WordApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
            //WordApp.System.Cursor = Word.WdCursorType.wdCursorWait;
            if (tabPage.Name == TabName.Replace(" ", "_").ToUpper())
            {
                FileUtilService service = FileUtilFactory.getInstance();
                //  service.clearIENetCache();
                showForm(Window, forms);
            }
            //TabPage tabPage = ((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab;
            if ((tabPage.Tag == null || true == (Boolean)tabPage.Tag) && !string.Equals(tabPage.Name, FieldConstants.TAB, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                var controls = WindowsFormControlUtils.GetControlHierarchy(tabPage);
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                {
                    
                    if (control is CustomGroupControl)
                    {
                        CustomGroupControl customGroupControl = (CustomGroupControl)control;
                        customGroupControl.fieldRenderDelegater();
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                
                tabPage.Tag = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }

       


 internal TableLayoutPanel createNewheaferTableLayoutPanel(string headerName)
        {
            TableLayoutPanel subHeaderTableLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
            // resources.ApplyResources(subHeaderTableLayout, headerName.Replace(" ", "_").ToUpper());
            subHeaderTableLayout.Name = headerName.Replace(" ", "_").ToUpper() + TABLE_LAYOUT_NAME_SUFFIX;
            subHeaderTableLayout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            subHeaderTableLayout.AutoSize = true;
            subHeaderTableLayout.AutoScroll = true;
            subHeaderTableLayout.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
            subHeaderTableLayout.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
            return subHeaderTableLayout;
        }
```

Comment: Apparently, you're creating Controls in a thread other than the UI Thread.

Comment: //TabPage tabPage = ((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab; How is the code working if this is quoted out? try gets null reference in ex.Message? By the way, you could have left out the screenshot. ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong I haven't seen the constructor.

Comment: @Lucky can you click on the link "Screenshot for above query" for screenshot !

Comment: @Jimi can you please suggest what can be done to fix this sort of issue?

Comment: Don't create Controls in a worker Thread.

Answer (score 0):

@Jimi & @Lucky

It works. Got the correct direction. Thanks.

Hint - Don't create controls on worker thread
Tried solution and worked - Removed creation of controls from parameterized constructor and added on form_load event.